# Errors linking Lapack to CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, armadillo, lapack

I am having issues running [Armadillo](https://arma.sourceforge.net/) library in my Code::Blocks 20.03 on Windows. I am always stuck on some kind of error and would really appreciate help.

I have downloaded the [LAPACK](https://icl.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/index.html#libraries) libraries, the x64 dll and lib files for Ref BLAS, LAPACK and LAPACKE.

I have them placed in a suitable folder, I have:
Linked the libraries in `Settings>Linker Settings`, added `path\libblas.lib, liblapack.lib, liblapacke.lib`.
Linked the libraries in `Project>Build options>Linker settings`, added `libblas.lib, liblapack.lib, liblapacke.lib`.
I have modified the armadillo `config.hpp` according to their readme file. The further that I got (the newest error) is:

```
||=== Build: Debug in 'project' (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld.exe||cannot find -lblas.lib|
ld.exe||cannot find -llapack.lib|
ld.exe||cannot find -llapacke.lib|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 7 second(s)) ===|
```

But those aren't the names of the libraries that I have linked. I have no idea where they come from, I have not recieved this error prior to linking these libraries.

I would appreciate any helpful comments. All the readme-s and documentations to installing and linking libraries either don't exist for CB or are written for someone who already actually knows how to do this and I am literally doing this for the first time ever. I feel a strong urge to add "Get a Linux-based system" is not a helpful comment :)
Thanks, I am getting desperate :)

Comment: remove the lib prefix and the .lib suffix and see if that helps. `ld` usually wants the undecorated name of the library. Eg: blas.

Comment: Sidenote: I'm used to GCC library files having a .a extension rather than .lib. This may be different on Windows, but you might also have library helper files compiled for Visual Studio.

Comment: removing the .lib prefix/suffix didn't help :/ these are the files that I've managed to get from the lapack website.